# Software installation on computers in a domain environment

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

The network I am working on is extremely small, my client only have 2 desktops which are in a domain setup being managed by a Windows Server 2012 machine with active directory.

My client has a couple different weather programs they are running on their two machines. These weather programs require you insert a code which in turn lets the software authenticate and download the RADAR information.

When I login under a user account and insert the code. Everything works as it is suppose to. When you log off the users account however and re-login again, their code isn't saving, which means you have to re-insert it every time a user logs in.

What is unusual to me is I have 1 account that everything works perfectly fine on. I can login and off and the software remembers the codes and that's it. All the other accounts however I have to re-enter the codes in every time they login.

All of the user accounts are domain administrators and all accounts have the exact same permissions. Can anyone give me any suggestions on where or what I need to do fix this issue?

Thank you.

---

Thank you for the responses. I believe I may have to look further into GPOs even though I am not very familiar with them. After spending the last few hours experimenting I was able to figure out that the issue is within the registry (I think).

When I install the software as local admin, insert the codes to make it work, everything works as it should. I can log-off and back in and everything is good.

When I login as a user of the domain, I insert the codes, everything works, but when I log-out and back in, the codes are erased and I have to insert them again (have to do this every time you login/out).

So, after hours of experimenting, I finally re-installed the software under a domain user account, however, I changed the install directory to an altered name so it didn't over-ride the local admins installation. Upon doing so, I entered the codes logged off and back on and everything worked great. However, when I logged in to the local admin account, the codes had been erased.

With that, I am left to believe that the issue lies within the registry. However, this is as far as I have made it and am not really sure how to proceed from here.

How can I install this software, get the codes inserted, and make it so when users login to this machine with their domain user accounts the software will remember what code to use?

Comment: I named the tool you can use to figure this out : Process Monitor from Sysinternals (Microsoft). Go download it, read the documentation, and give it a shot. Any new questions should be posted as new questions. Don't forget to mark an accepted answer on this question. Welcome to Server Fault!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a question for the vendor.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing I would do is read the documentation on the weather programs. 
The second thing I would do is contact the vendor for the weather programs.

It may be that this software doesn't work properly as a non-admin account and won't save the password, in which case you should hope they have a workaround that does not involve granting local administrator access to the users for their machines.

If the vendor is clueless, you could try running Process Monitor from Sysinternals (Microsoft), to determine why the password isn't being saved properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is frequent problem, especially when using old or not properly developed apps. It works well with admin privileged but not working properly or even not work at all. Moreover, software support for these types of apps never helps, at least in my case.

I advise you search files or registry values that your app want to use, do this with admin rights. Next using GPO (take a look how to create new group policy object located [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756952(v=ws.10).aspx)) grant read, write or all privileges to folders and registry keys for domain users group. Use This should works well.

P.S. To find correct registry keys, your app is using I will advise you to use [Sysinternals Process Monitor v3.1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)